# How to implement shacl rules

Tags: rdf, rule-engine, shacl

Are there any pre-built rule-engines for SHACL?

I'm currently using pyshacl, which does support the rule-engine, but does not update the data graph with the new statements.

Comment: did you enable the advanced features? And for me it makes sense to leave the data graph as is, most likely the inferred triples are in the result graph. Just in case, I'd simply contact the devs, the lead dev Ashley Sommer via Ashley.Sommer@csiro.au

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is about SHACL-AF inference rules (https://w3c.github.io/shacl/shacl-af/#rules) then the TopBraid SHACL API does have support, including a shaclinfer command line tool.

https://github.com/TopQuadrant/shacl

The term "rule" is overloaded and some people call validation constraints also rules, so I am not 100% sure what you are referring to.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the SHACL-AF inference rules. Sorry for the confusion.